# in r combine a list of lists into one list

Tags: r, list

I cannot find out can to get a list of all entry of the sublists? Here's a simple example, a list o lists:

```
listoflists <- list("A"=list(c(1,2,3),c(2,34,2)), "B" = list(c(1,2),c(2,3,2,1)), "C" = list(c("sdf",3,2)))
$A
$A[[1]]
[1] 1 2 3

$A[[2]]
[1]  2 34  2


$B
$B[[1]]
[1] 1 2

$B[[2]]
[1] 2 3 2 1


$C
$C[[1]]
[1] "sdf" "3"   "2"
```

I only found this sad way by using a for-loop:

```
listofvectors <- list()
for (i in 1:length(listoflists))  {listofvectors <- c(listofvectors, listoflists[[i]])}
```

Comment: `purrr::flatten(listoflists)` should do it.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

We can use the concatenate function (`c`) within `do.call` to flatten the nested `list`

```
res <- do.call(c, listoflists)
all.equal(listofvectors, res, check.attributes = FALSE)
#[1] TRUE
```

Or as @d.b mentioned in the comments, `unlist` with `recursive = FALSE` can also work

```
unlist(listoflists, recursive = FALSE)
```

Comment: OR `unlist(listoflists, recursive = FALSE)`

Answer (score 4):

For your specific example, which does not have much nesting, you can also just use `flatten` from the "purrr" package.

```
library(purrr)
flatten(listoflists)
```

However, you don't specify the behavior you'd expect for more deeply nested lists. If you want to fully flatten a more deeply nested list, you can look at the **[`LinearizeNestedList`](https://gist.github.com/mrdwab/4205477)** function by [Akhil S Bhel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1533691/asb).

Example:

```
LL <- list(listoflists, listoflists)
str(flatten(LL))  ## Same as `do.call(c, LL)`
# List of 6
#  $ A:List of 2
#   ..$ : num [1:3] 1 2 3
#   ..$ : num [1:3] 2 34 2
#  $ B:List of 2
#   ..$ : num [1:2] 1 2
#   ..$ : num [1:4] 2 3 2 1
#  $ C:List of 1
#   ..$ : chr [1:3] "sdf" "3" "2"
#  $ A:List of 2
#   ..$ : num [1:3] 1 2 3
#   ..$ : num [1:3] 2 34 2
#  $ B:List of 2
#   ..$ : num [1:2] 1 2
#   ..$ : num [1:4] 2 3 2 1
#  $ C:List of 1
#   ..$ : chr [1:3] "sdf" "3" "2"
str(LinearizeNestedList(LL))
# List of 10
#  $ 1/A/1: num [1:3] 1 2 3
#  $ 1/A/2: num [1:3] 2 34 2
#  $ 1/B/1: num [1:2] 1 2
#  $ 1/B/2: num [1:4] 2 3 2 1
#  $ 1/C/1: chr [1:3] "sdf" "3" "2"
#  $ 2/A/1: num [1:3] 1 2 3
#  $ 2/A/2: num [1:3] 2 34 2
#  $ 2/B/1: num [1:2] 1 2
#  $ 2/B/2: num [1:4] 2 3 2 1
#  $ 2/C/1: chr [1:3] "sdf" "3" "2"
```

Answer (score 0):

how about the following?

```
A = list(c(1,2,3),c(2,34,2))
B = list(c(1,2),c(2,3,2,1))
C = list(c("sdf",3,2))
joint_list <- c(A, B, C)
```