# R: How to concatenate vectors of strings in a list of vectors

Tags: r, string, list

I have a list of vectors of strings like this:

```
x=list(c("a","b"),"c",c("d","e","f"),c("gg","hh") )
```

I'd like to concatenate the vectors into single strings like this

```
y=c("ab","c","def","gghh")
```

I searched [around](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43281902/in-r-combine-a-list-of-lists-into-one-list) but I couldn't find a similar example. Is there a smart way to do this without looping over the list elements?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With `sapply`:

```
y <- sapply(x, paste0, collapse = '')
# [1] "ab"   "c"    "def"  "gghh"
```

Comment: You probably know this already, but FYI for those interested, `paste0` and `paste` will give the same result in cases like this where there's only one argument (other than `collapse`)

Answer (score -1):

It's not the most elegant solution but this works:

```
x=list(c("a","b"),"c",c("d","e","f"),c("gg","hh") )

y=NULL
for(i in 1:length(x)){
  y=c(y,paste0(x[[i]],collapse=""))
}
```