# Function to combine multiple lists of lists into a single list of lists?

Tags: r, data-wrangling

Suppose we have list `l` which is a list of lists.

```
a <- list(c(1,2,3))
b <- list(c(4,5,6), c(7,8,9))
c <- list(c(10,11,12), c(13,14,15), c(16,17,18))

l <- list(a, b, c)
```

So `l` is a list of lists, where each of those lists itself contains at least one list.

#### Question

How can I make a function which can extract all the lowest level lists into a single list of lists?

```
# Goal
list(c(1,2,3), c(4,5,6), c(7,8,9), c(10,11,12), c(13,14,15), c(16,17,18))
```

Notes:

- The example is a minimal reproducible example for which it would be possible to hard-code a solution, but it is important that the solution generalise, since the real problem has tens-of-thousands of lists each containing unknown numbers of lists - so a hard-coded solution definitely won't scale!
- I hope to find a solution in base R, if possible.

#### A few things I've tried so far

Some unsuccessful attempts, mostly using `sapply()` and `unlist()`:

```r
sapply(l, function(x) { unlist(x) })
# [[1]]
# [1] 1 2 3
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] 4 5 6 7 8 9
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18

unlist(a)
# [1] 1 2 3

# unlist() seems to combine the elements of multiple lists into one list (not desired here)..
unlist(b)
# [1] 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

I thought the [`recursive = FALSE`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43281952/5783745) argument looked promising, but unfortunately I couldn't get it to do what I wanted either:

```r
unlist(b, recursive = FALSE)
# [1] 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

Comment: Have you seen this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16300344/how-to-flatten-a-list-of-lists

Comment: @Skaqqs thanks. I had seen it (linked to it in the question), but I hadn't applied it correctly! Thanks again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `unlist`, non-recursive on your initial list.

```
unlist(l, recursive=FALSE)
# [[1]]
# [1] 1 2 3
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] 4 5 6
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] 7 8 9
# 
# [[4]]
# [1] 10 11 12
# 
# [[5]]
# [1] 13 14 15
# 
# [[6]]
# [1] 16 17 18
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use `unlist()`:

```
a <- list(c(1,2,3))
b <- list(c(4,5,6), c(7,8,9))
c <- list(c(10,11,12), c(13,14,15), c(16,17,18))
l <- list(a, b, c)

l.want <- list(c(1,2,3), c(4,5,6), c(7,8,9), c(10,11,12), c(13,14,15), c(16,17,18))

#Use unlist
l.func <- unlist(l, recursive = F)

all.equal(l.want, l.func)
# TRUE
```